# When to use metamask and ethereum wallet

Tags: truffle, ethereum-wallet-dapp, metamask

I am confused with metamask and ethereum wallet and Truffle. 
I used metamask in Truffle Petshop tutorial. 
Then I am using now ethereum wallet with first voting dapp. 
I m confused totally

Answer (score 1):

Basically they both have the same goal: **Browse the Web3**, you can use it to access a dApp (Decentralized Application). So that shouldn't do any difference to use one or the other.

A Web3 browser is a browser that can browse Internet but also execute Blockchain transactions. For that, the browser includes a wallet that contains one or more private keys) in order to sign transactions.

The difference between Metamask and Ethereum Wallet is the following:

- **Ethereum Wallet / MIST** is a full Ethereum browser/wallet,
- **Metamask** is only a Chrome extension which transform Chrome into a Web3 browser by adding a wallet and injecting the web3js library in the web page.

**Truffle** is a completely different thing. It's a framework to develop and deploy dApp.

Comment: How to start with dapps..? Any suggestions would be helpful.. And previous work if any..!

Comment: Ethereum wallet is taking lot of time..

Comment: I recently bookmarked this [tweet thread](https://twitter.com/JimmyRagosa/status/953667960681443335?s=09) that summarizes a bunch of tutorials and resources to develop dapps:

Comment: By "taking some time", do you mean "take time to sync the blockchain". Because by default with EthereumWallet, you host your own blockckain node which takes time to sync. While Metamask by default connect to a public node (like Infura) which is always sync.

Comment: Being picky here. You stated both are Web3 Browsers. I can't take MetaMask, alone as is, and browse the web. Yes, you correctly state it on later with their descriptions :)

Comment: No worries, you right. Updated the wording to avoid the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

**Metamask** - Allows you to quickly connect to different testnet's, or the main net and interact with the network without running a node.

https://metamask.io/

**Truffle** - allows you to test/deploy contracts, keep version history.

http://truffleframework.com/

Both do different things, I could easily see you using both within a single project.